# Can you simulate three keys simultaneously with "Windows Input Simulator"?

Tags: c#

I working in C# with the "Windows Input Simulator" library.
I realize that using the following lines I similare two keystrokes:

**InputSimulator input = new InputSimulator();
input.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.SUBTRACT);**

But how do I simulate three keystrokes simultaneously?

Comment: You can send multiple modifier (CTRL, ALT, WIN...) but only 1 key (1, M, L, -, Q)

Answer (score 1):

`ModifiedKeyStroke` can receive an array of modifiers and an array of keys, for instance if you want to press Ctrl+Shift+K you can use:

```
input.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(
    new[] { VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT },
    new[] { VirtualKeyCode.VK_K }
);
```

I recommend you to read this post: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/520/simulating-keypress-in-the-right-way-using-inputsimulator-with-csharp-in-winforms